# Android: need to get full information for selectitem from listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I getting full information like Country ID,Country Name & Description from WCF Webservice & i have successfully populate in listview which display Country Name only.Now when i select one of the country name in listview for editing,I must get all of the details like country ID & description but i manage to get country name only.Can anyone please guide me.thanks in advance.

```
        //Populate Country Name in Listview 

        String jsonInput=wcfItems;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{ 

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonInput);
      int length = jsonArray.length();
      List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
          splitItem=jsonArray.getString(i).split(",");
              //splitItem[0].toString().trim() -->is ID
              //splitItem[2].toString().trim() -->is Description
          listContents.add(splitItem[1].toString().trim() ); //Country Name
      }

      ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));
```

---

```
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
            //Didn't get country_ID
    String country_ID=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //Manage to get country_name only
            String country_Name=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //Didn't get Description
    String country_Description=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    getRateItems(country_ID,country_Name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the `jsonArray` as the Activity member, so later in the `onItemSelected()` you can get the same `splitItem` via `jsonArray.getString(position)`.